# Spring AOP logger, pointcut definition

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm trying to introduce a logger in my project using Spring AOP, but I'm new to AOP and to AspectJ syntax, so I'm having some troubles...

I've defined a basic aspect-class following some tutorial/docs:

```
@Aspect
public class Logger {

    @Pointcut("execution(* exportdatamanager.export.ExportType.fetch(..))")
    public void fetch() {
    }

    // ...

    @AfterReturning("fetch()")
    public void fetchingResult(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        System.out.println("TEST LOG " + result.toString());
    }
}
```

But when I run my application I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
```

What I'm doing wrong, I suppose there's something wrong in my ApsectJ expression...

Can you also suggest me **some quick reference to AspectJ syntax** supported by Spring AOP?

**NOTE**

A snippet from my `ExportType` interface

```
public interface ExportType {

    List<Object> fetch() throws FetchingStrategyException;

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just solved my issue this way:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "fetch()", returning = "results")
public void fetchingResult(JoinPoint joinPoint, List<Object> results) {
    System.out.println("TEST LOG " + results.toString());
}
```